# sharepoint 2010 and tagcloud

Tags: crawling, tags

Having issues with crawling and tag cloud. Is it a requirament to run full crawling in sharepoint 2010 every time, when i add a new document with tags? I tried incremental, but afrer that new tag profile isn't showing anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tag cloud stuff in SP2010 is somewhat circuitous. The process works like this:

1. At the document library you enable metadata publishing  (Library
   Settings > Enterprise Metadata and Keyword Settings. Check 'Save
   metadata on this list as Social tags'
2. Once that's been enabled an
   event receiver will push any new or edited MMS column values to the
   social tags store (which is part of the user profile service)
3. Every hour the 'User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance
   Job' will run, which will run through the new tags that have been
   added to the tag store and will add them to the list of tags
   available for display in the tag cloud.

So if tags aren't appearing in the cloud things to check are:

- Tag promotion is enabled
- MMS values were changed or added after tag promotion was enabled
- User Profile service is healthy
- Social Data Maintenance job has run since changes were made

If tags are appearing in the tag cloud but there are no documents showing with those tags on the tag profile page then the issue is somewhat different. The crawling process should work like this:

1. Item is added to the library and tags are promoted
2. This item must get crawled before the SocialTag can be associated with it
3. The social data maintenance job compiles tags into a format that can be queried by the tag cloud (as above)
4. Running this job flags the adding user's account for re-crawl during People Crawl
5. People crawl retrieves the social tags for each item and adds them to the property store
6. Once they're in the property store all will be well in the world.

So things to check are:

- All requirement property mappings are in place - see [this post for the specifics](http://weshackett.com/2010/07/getting-tags-to-display-their-profile-and-search/)
- You have people crawl setup in your default content source (ie. sps3://mysite.domain.com or sps3s://mysite.domain.com if it is a secure site)

Comment: thank you! so the main problem is that tags are appearing in the cloud but there are no documents with those tags. they only appear when i peform full crawling. I did everthing what is mentioned in link below but no success.